# Archive option in tools menu in visual studio 2015 not active

Tags: visual-studio

Archive option in tools menu in visual studio 2015 not active

[image]

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a standard menu item in VS2015. Do you have some extension tool installed?

Comment: could you explain more
?